# Custom image FOR NAVIGATION Retina image Issue

Tags: ios, objective-c

okay so i am using an Image for navigation bar using the  Following Code

```
 UIImage *special = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone-title-BarText.png"];
[self.navigationController.navigationBar setBackgroundImage:special forBarMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
```

and i am using two versions of 'iphone-title-BarText.png' as 320 X 45 and for @2x.png as 640 X 90.

Now the Problem i am facing is that if i am using

```
UIImage *special = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone-title-BarText.png"];
```

then its not displaying my @2x image in iphone 5 (so the non retina image got pixelated.(app only Supports iphone 5) and if i use this

```
UIImage *special = [UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone-title-BarText@2x.png"];
```

then image at Navigation bar only Display Half (width) of the Retina image and for height it Twice the size of Navigation Bar .
let me know if you need any further clarification on this .

[image: screen shot]

Comment: You should double check your images. It sounds like @2x one may not be 640x90

Comment: Yes i did , even i deleted the App then, Clean the Project .and Run it again.

Comment: Also `[UIImage imageNamed:@"iphone-title-BarText]` will do, there is no need to add the `.png`